# Animate text inside button

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-animation

I have recyclerview with buttons of fixed size:

```
<Button
    android:text="Category"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/categoryButton"
    style="@style/custom_button" />
```

What I have when entering large text inside button:

[image: Large text]

But I want the text moving inside it if it larger than button width.

I am using Xamarin.Android but I will be glad to get any help even on Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the text to be scrolling horizontally you could use the 'marquee' attribute in the button.

Layout:

```
   <Button
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:ellipsize="marquee"
       android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:text="Abracadabra" />
```

And in the code; set selection of the button to true.

```
   button.setSelected(true)
```

Comment: It's EXACTLY what I need. Thank you so much. But is it ok to make all buttons selected? What does it mean?

Comment: I wouldn't imagine so. As far as I understand; it simply sets an internal flag on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with ScrollView.

E.g.

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button
     android:text="Category"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/categoryButton"
     style="@style/custom_button" />
</ScrollView>
```